# How to extract a string from url in a weblog file using pig/hive

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

How to extract a string from url in a weblog file using pig/hive

input file

```
122.161.182.202 - jane [21/Jul/2012:13:14:17-0700] "GET /rss.pl HTTP/1.1"   200 35942 "http://www.e.com/bam_applicatin/VD55173061"     "IE/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;   Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;    OfficeLivePatch.1.3; MSOffice 12)"
```

Desired output:

```
122.161.182.202 - jane [21/Jul/2012:13:14:17-0700] "GET /rss.pl HTTP/1.1"   200 35942 "VD55173061"     "IE/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;   Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;    OfficeLivePatch.1.3; MSOffice 12)"
```

input url 
http://www.e.com/bam_applicatin/VD55173061

Desired String from the url
VD55173061

I want to process the weblog using pig or hive. Please help ..

Answer (score 1):

Using **Apache Pig**

Refer [http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#substring](http://Pig%20Docs) for API docs and usage

**Input :**

```
http://www.e.com/bam_applicatin/VD55173061
```

**Pig script :**

```
url_data = LOAD 'input.csv' USING  PigStorage(',') AS  (url:chararray);
req_url = FOREACH url_data GENERATE SUBSTRING(url,LAST_INDEX_OF(url, '/') + 1, (int)SIZE(url));
DUMP req_url;
```

**Output :**

```
VD55173061
```

Comment: my input - 122.161.182.202 - jane [21/Jul/2012:13:14:17-0700] "GET /rss.pl HTTP/1.1"   200 35942 "http://www.e.com/bam_applicatin/VD55173061"     "IE/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;   Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;    OfficeLivePatch.1.3; MSOffice 12)"

Comment: i want output like this 122.161.182.202 - jane [21/Jul/2012:13:14:17-0700] "GET /rss.pl HTTP/1.1"   200 35942 "VD55173061"     "IE/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;   Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;    OfficeLivePatch.1.3; MSOffice 12)"

Comment: @SivasaravanaKumar : Ref : http://hadooptutorial.info/processing-logs-in-pig/ and http://sumedha.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-use-apache-pig-to-analyze-log.html

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the string you would be extracting would have same length (10 here), you could use the `SUBSTR()` function.

> SUBSTR(string source_str, int start_position [,int length])

In your case, you can use something like

```
SUBSTR(url, (LENGTH(url)-(10-1))
```

You can refer to the [manual pages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) for more info.